# Open Safari With Numerous Tabs Open?

Tags: safari, macos

When I use Chrome I like the feature that enables me to open Chrome with a list of websites I always want to open up once I use it.

Is this feature available in Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the sites you want to use must be saved in a folder in your bookmarks.

Once you've bookmarked the sites all in the same folder (the only contents of the folder should be these sites), go to Safari -> Preferences -> General. Click the Choose Tabs Folder... item in the New windows open with: menu and select your folder.

New windows will open with each of your websites in tabs.

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is there a way to open new window with that option and to sometimes open empty new window?(the only way now is to open a new tab and then drag the tab out to become a window but that takes too much time)

Comment: @Anonymous What about opening a new window and then using `command-option-w` to close all tabs but the current one? You could make one of the tabs a blank page.

Comment: That's really nice -  I didn't knew this keybaord shortcut that's great. Thanks! I think I'm very happy with this solution! :-)